# jQuery Ajax checkbox value

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, checkbox

I have checkboxes on my page for which I would like to send their state back to the database via ajax. I know how to use jquery with ajax and how to work with SELECT and OPTIONS, but I don't know to do the same things with several checkboxes and how to get the value from them.
Everything works when id is attached to one checkbox, but when i attach id to several checkboxes it doen'twork(except first check box)

Any ideas?

my code looks like this->

```
       <form>
          <div class="checkbox" >
            <label><input type="checkbox" value="1" id="item">что то</label>
            <label><input type="checkbox" value="1" id="item">Шорты</label>
            <label><input type="checkbox" value="3" id="item">Классическая</label>
          </div>
</form>



 <script>
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#item').on('click',function(){


    var name = $('#item').val();
    $.post('load.php', {name:name}, function(data){
        $('#name-data').html(data);
    });
});

});
</script>
```

Comment: Are you attaching the same ID to multiple checkboxes?  That won't work; ids need to be unique.

Comment: I've added my code

Answer (score 0):

Use a class.  Ids are expected to be unique on a single page.  Classes are used to group elements together.

```
<tag id="a">A</tag><tag id="a">B</tag>  $('#a')
becomes
<tag class="a">A</tag><tag class="a">B</tag>  $('.a')
```

Answer (score 0):

`Id` should be unique  you can use `class` instead of `Id`.

Comment: is it possible tto give an id for banch of checkboxes , as in the case of SELECT and OPTION?